# from a list of binaries print the one that includes a specific ascii string

Tags: linux, grep

I have a folder with some binaries.

What I want to do is to print all the files that
include a specific ascii string.

With the following commands

```
strings * | grep <string>
```

I can check that at least, somewhere the string exists,
but how I can get the specific binary?

Thanks and happy new year!

Comment: http://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html

Comment: You can't do it that way, because using `string *` looses the file information.

Comment: [Grep — list file name where match is found](https://askubuntu.com/q/587197), [Find and echo file names only with pattern found](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/342008/56041), [Find files containing string in file name and different string within file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/248761/56041), etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With gnu grep (the one you find e.g. in linux):

```
grep -aH <string> *
```

If you want to suppress the ugly output and only keep the files that do match:

```
grep -al <string> *
```